# How to debug React varaibles from Chrome REPL

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, google-chrome

I have a React TypeScript app that defines something like this:

index.tsx

```
import './initDefaultAccessContext';
```

Then in initDefaultAccessContext.ts I have something defined.

```
const appName = 'something123';
```

If I'm debugging the application in chrome how can I access appName from the REPL.

```
> appName 
and
> window.appName
```

Both of the above return undefined.

How do you access variable / anything that's been defined in code this way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
> window.appName
```

you cannot write in the console `window.appName` and expect it to return the value because `appName` is scoped to the module (and not to the global object) that internally is just an [IIFE](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/IIFE), the only way to see runtime the value of `appName` is by adding a breakpoint inside the file to the specific line you're interested to and see its value there.

Comment: Oh, thank you, yes that makes sense. Sorry I think I may have over simplified my question. Let me update the question with a better example.

Answer (score 0):

If you have source maps enabled, you can go to the chrome dev tools, press Command+O or Command+P in mac OR press Control+O or Control+P in Windows / Linux to open your source code file (you can search by the source file name) in the sources panel. Once you find and open your file, you need to find the line which you are looking for and then add a breakpoint by clicking on the line number column. (Visit this link for more info on [chrome breakpoint](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/javascript/breakpoints))

Once breakpoint is set, reload the page and you can see that the browser pauses javascript execution at the breakpoint. Now you can switch to the console tab in devtools and type in the variable names `appName` or `window.appName`

There is one more way to set breakpoint without actually going to the sourcemaps in devtools. Just add the statement `debugger;` in your source code, on the line where you want to set the breakpoint. But, if you're following this approach, you should be very careful and make sure that you remember to delete this statement after debugging. If you forget to delete the `debugger;` statement and the code goes to production environment, the javascript will pause the execution when users use your application.

Comment: Thanks you, that is helpful. I just edited my question as I provided a poor example to begin with.